# Runtime Error in C++

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

I am running this program on codeblocks where it runs fine but in an online judge it gives a Runtime error for the input same input.
I cannot figure out what could be the cause of this error.

```
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &numbers, int target)
    {

     vector<int> c ;

    sort(numbers.begin(),numbers.end()-1);

    vector<int>::iterator i = numbers.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator j = numbers.end()-1;

    while(i<=j)
    {
        int sum = *i + *j;
        if(sum==target)
                           { c.push_back(i-numbers.begin());
                             c.push_back(j-numbers.begin());
                             //cout<<*i<<" "<<*j<<endl;
                             break;

                           }
        else if(sum<target) i++;
        else j--;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: I'd give you two points less for using a class unnecessarily and for not indenting your code consistently. In any case, your twoSum() function is broken when given an empty vector, maybe there's a few more corner cases you forgot to check for?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sir, this format is the standard for most of the online judges in C++/Java i.e. wrapping solutions inside class methods. Please consider your downvote or else I could be banned from asking any questions.

Comment: Are you sure it crashed with that exact input, and not with an empty vector input?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, it crashed with empty vector.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question here, but just because some other website requests a certain format, you should still honour this site's rule that code should be readable and reduced to a bare minimum. That said, it also helps *you* to find the error, because you have to concentrate on the essentials.

Comment: @edbale But you claim it crashed with the input you show. Did it also crash with that?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, the online judge claims it crashed with that but with CodeBlocks it doesn't.

Comment: @edbale That's the problem with online judge questions. Almost no one here knows about their inner workings and decision process. You'll have to find out what's wrong at their site. Nevertheless, that you have different behaviors, speaks for you've been hitting undefined behavior.

Comment: The "problem" is that online judges **will** test edge cases, such as empty inputs, inputs of the maximum length, inputs where all the values are identical etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sort(numbers.begin(),numbers.end()-1);
```

Calling this on a empty `numbers` vector leads to runtime error. It should be `sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());`

Comment: Do you mean an empty vector? 1 element should be fine.

Comment: ...but for an empty vector, `numbers.end() - 1` yields UB already.

Comment: Fixed error. Yes, the problem happens on empty vector, not single-element vector.